# Prove that extension of a function is a surjection?

Tags: general-topology, logic, compactness, model-theory

I am doing work with model theory and came across the following exercise:

"Consider a set $Y$ in some structure $\mathcal{M}$. Let $f:Y\to C$ be a definable map to a compact space $C$, with dense image. Suppose $Y\subseteq Y^{*}$. Then there is a unique extension of $f$ to $Y^{*}$, called $f^{*}$, that is M-definable. $f^{*}(a) = \cap_{\alpha \in p} \overline{f(\alpha(M))}$ where $p = tp(a/\mathcal{M})$.
Prove that this extension is surjective. "

So my thought to use the dense image of $f$ since we know that the preimage of dense set under an onto map will be dense also. But I was unable to show that this would be the case.

Outline of my unsuccessful attempt. I don't know if this can work, or whether need to start over:

I try to use the definable map and $\mathcal{M}$-definable map properties. 
So if $f$ is definable, we can find a definable set $Y_{0}\subseteq Y$ such that for disjoint closed sets $C_{1},C_{2}\subseteq C$ (which will also be compact) $C_{1}\subseteq Y_{0}$ and $C_{2}\cap Y_{0} = \emptyset.$ 
For an $\mathcal{M}$ definable map, like our $f^{*}$, preimage of closed set is type definable.
So maybe I show that the whole of $Y^{*}$ is dense?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You're using some terminology and notation that I'm not familiar with. What is $Y^*$? What does it mean to say that a map from a subset of a structure to a topological space is definable? Just that the preimage of every closed set is type-definable?

Comment: You could also let us know where the exercise comes from, to provide a reference for the notation.

Comment: The question is based on section 3 from the paper "On compactifications and the topological dynamics of definable groups". My understanding is that $Y^{*}$ is just a set in structure $\mathcal{M}$  that contains $Y$. The (0)-definable map has the criterion for closed disjoint sets, while the $\mathcal{M}$-definable map has the type-definable preimage.

Comment: No, $Y^*$ is not just any definable set containing $Y$. This notation is defined right at the beginning of Section 3 of that paper: "$M^*$ denotes a very saturated elementary extension of $M$. For $Y$ a definable set in $M$, we often use $Y^*$ to denote the interpretation in $M^*$ of the formula which defines $Y$ in $M$." So the idea is to use the fact that $f$ is definable with dense image to find, for any point $x\in C$, a type $p_x$  with the property that if $a$ realizes $p_x$, then $f^*(a) = x$. And then, since $M^*$ is saturated, $p_x$ is realized in $Y^*$.

Comment: I don't have time now, so I'll leave it to someone (maybe you!) to work out the details based on that sketch.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I selected an arbitrary point $x$ in C, and considered an open neighbourhood of $x$ along with the complement of that neighbourhood. Then I pick a smaller closed neighbourhood of $x$ within the open neighbourhood, and using the definability of $f$ I get a definable set in $Y$ whose image under $f$ is subset of my open neighbourhood. Then I make another open neighbourhood of $x$ inside the first closed neighbourhood and repeat the process to keep getting smaller definable sets that approach simply having $x$. Then I think I should get a type from the definable sets?

Comment: Sounds like the right idea to me. I suggest you write down the details as an answer and accept it.